# Regex for contact number that does/doesn't start with a +

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, numbers, contact-form

I have tried to create a basic South African contact number regex. Its not working though. The rules are simple.

10 digits or 
11 digits if it starts with a +

Examples:
0119879874
0731231234
+27731231234
+27123456789

It must match only digits and length.
My attempt: `[+\d]\d{9}\d{0,2}`
I tested on the site https://regex101.com/ and it looked like it worked but not when i test it with `/[+\d]\d{9}\d{0,2}/.test('12345gjhf6789123456'))` then i get a true value.

Comment: I guess you mean 10 digits if it starts with a + (since a + is not a digit)

Comment: Its South African international number starts with +27 so a number that is normally 073 123 4567 would be +2773 123 4567. Its the same with land line numbers so it will be 11 digits if it has a + to start. @ifran434 i tried your regex on the test site i linked but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `^` - begin of the  string and end `$` 
and

```
/^(\+\d)?\d{10}$/.test('12345gjhf6789123456'))
```

Comment: i tried your regex on the site i linked but its giving me a error

Comment: Apologies for not being more detailed. It says ""+ The preceding token is not quantifiable"" when i attempt to test it on the regex site

Comment: Sorry i forget a `\`. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a regex that will not provide any error messaging and is difficult to read (and maintain), I would suggest a simple validation function that lays out the rules explicitly:

```
function validate(num) {
  if (num[0] === '+') {
    return num.length === 11;
  } else {
    return num.length === 10;
  }
}
```

This has a few advantages, including:

- faster than a regex
- easier to comment and expand later
- can be replaced with a full blown predicate library or just an array of rules

Comment: Thanks I was going to use this method but unfortunately it has to be a regex that i use